# Mod Rewrite under certain circumstances

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My website has the following structure

```
/index.php
/anotherpage.php
/login/
/view/
```

I have set up a mod rewrite inside the /view/ directory so that /view/?id=aBc123 is accessible from /view/aBc123

but what I am trying to achieve is a way to be able to remove the /view/ from that URL without disturbing the rest of the site.

so that the URL looks like

```
domain.com/aBc123
```

but so that the following is not affected

```
domain.com/index.php
domain.com/anotherpage.php
domain.com/login
domain.com/view
```

Note that there is a lot more legitimate directories and files on the actual site, just showing these as examples of scenarios I want to continue to work.

So the scenario is to treat it as an ID when its not a .php file and when its not a legitimate directory.

I am trying to work out what the mod rewrite is for this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!view/).*) view/$1 [L,NC]
```